# How do you save custom fields along with the user/saveUser action?

Tags: plugin-development, users

We are building a simple user import plugin, saving the basic user is easy enough but how does one save data to the custom fields added to users

Basic exmaple:

```
$user = new UserModel();
$user->status = UserStatus::Active;
$user->firstName = 'Fruit';
$user->lastName = 'Studios';
$user->email = 'email@domain.com';
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

This all works great but i cant work out how I add the custom fields?? The following will abviously not work because 'postCode' is not part of the User Model:

```
$user->postCode = 'SO23 9UG';
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried $user->postCode and what happens when you do?

Comment: Throws an error: `Property "Craft\UserModel.postCode" is not defined.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, just need to use the getContent() function exactly the same as entries:

```
$user->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
    'postCode' => 'SO23 9UG',
));
```